# c++ What's the use of pointers in a vector container

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

I saw this here: http://pastebin.com/6Q7zS7tC and wondered why are these pointers "needed" or can be efficiently used when they are initiated as pointers?
The string pointer in the vector container and the coord struct pointer inside the vector container.

```
class objloader{
std::vector<std::string*> coord;        //every line of code from the obj file
std::vector<coordinate*> vertex;        //all vertexes
std::vector<face*> faces;                                       //all faces
std::vector<coordinate*> normals;       //all normal vectors
std::vector<GLuint> texture;
std::vector<unsigned int> lists;        //the id for all lists (so we can delete the lists after use it)
std::vector<material*> materials;       //all materials
std::vector<texcoord*> texturecoordinate;       //all texture coorinate (UV coordinate)
bool ismaterial,isnormals,istexture;    //obvious
unsigned int loadTexture(const char* filename); //private load texture function
void clean();   //free all of the used memory
public:
objloader();
~objloader();   //free the textures and lists
int load(const char* filename); //the main model load function
};
```

Comment: They probably aren't needed.

Comment: Your question is unclear/too broad without giving more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to tell if they are "needed" from what you posted.  They may be needed depending on how this code is implemented.  You would need to review the ENTIRE program to understand its overall design in order to determine if there are alternatives to using pointers in these containers.

Holding pointers in a container like this is very common.

Yes, holding pointers in a container is efficient.

CAUTION:  Any time you have a container of pointers, you have to be sure the objects pointed to get deleted properly.  Calling delete on the vector does not free the memory used by the objects pointed to by the pointers.  Three common ways to ensure proper memory management when storing pointers in a container are:

1. Loop through the container and call delete on each individual pointer
2. Use smart pointers instead of regular pointers
3. Use a boost pointer container instead of STL container

Answer (score 0):

The STL library makes extensive use of copying to (re)arrange members within containers. So typically pointers are used if objects are expensive to copy. General advise is to avoid pointers however as storing pointers in STL containers can quite easily generate memory leaks. To get around this you can write an encapsulating class (which should of course be cheap to copy) or use either the Boost smart pointers or the new C++11 smart ptrs.

Answer (score 0):

`position` has only an explicit constructor that takes arguments, so it needs to be a pointer to be used in a container. But `std::string` doesn't have the same limitation.